# How can one change the size of a sun lamp in Blender 2.79?

Tags: light

I can't seem to find out where to change the size of the sun lamp. When I look under the sun lamp properties, it only displays "Energy" instead of "Size". Can someone help me with this?

Comment: are you talking about 2.79 or 2.8? I can't see Energy in 2.79 (or in 2.8 but I don't have the latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun light size has now been replaced by an angular size, which makes more sense for this type of light source.

You can control it from *Angle* property in the *Object Data* panel in the *Properties Window*.

[image]